# Customize bad request HTTP400 page Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, bad-request

Is it possible to customize the html page returned from Spring when a bad request is done and returned HTTP400 error code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this.

You need to define global error handler ***ControllerAdvice*** annotation.

Example code will be:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {

        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw e;

        // setup and send the user to a default error-view.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

For further reading:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html
2. https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Yogi answer 2 more alternatives:

1. If you are using a **web.xml** there is a very convenient options to provide a View page dedicated per HTTP Error Code

> ```
> <error-page>
>    <error-code>400</error-code>
>    <location>/WEB-INF/my/location/to/http/errors/400.jsp</location>
> </error-page>
> ```

2. **Spring Boot** also provides a very convenient way to do the same with the additional option to offer View pages for groups of http error categories. [Take a look at the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages). In short you can provide the View pages or HTTP-Error-Code-group pages under an `/error` directory under the `/resources` directory (convenient convention-over-configuration approach).